# 'ndk-build' error while compiling the source code

Tags: android-ndk

I am following the following tutorial:
http://taylorpeer.com/hello-world-cpp-android-ndk/

When I run *ndk-build* in the terminal, I get the following errors:

```
Compile++ thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.cpp
jni/hello-jni.cpp:4:5: error: stray '\342' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:4:5: error: stray '\200' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:4:5: error: stray '\234' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:4:5: error: stray '\342' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:4:5: error: stray '\200' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:4:5: error: stray '\235' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\342' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\200' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\234' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\342' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\200' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\235' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:4:15: error: 'C' does not name a type
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

Following is the list of my files:

#### Java file found in the *src* folder

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Hellojnicpp extends Activity {
          /** Called when the activity is first created. */
          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                /** Create a TextView and set it to display
                * text loaded from a native method.
                */
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
                setContentView(tv);
          }
          /** A native method that is implemented by the
          * ‘hello-jni’ native library, which is packaged
          * with this application.
          */
          public native String stringFromJNI();
          /** Load the native library where the native method
          * is stored.
          */
          static {
                System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
          }
    }
```

#### *Android.mk* file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

#### *.cpp* file

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern “C” {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
    Java_com_example_Hellojnicpp_stringFromJNI
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF(“Hello from C++ over JNI!”);
    }
}
```

How can I fix the errors?

I am now getting the following error after changing *"C"* to "C":

```
Compile++ thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.cpp
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\342' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\200' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\234' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\342' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\200' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:17: error: stray '\235' in program
jni/hello-jni.cpp: In function '_jstring* Java_com_example_Hellojnicpp_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv*, jobject)':
jni/hello-jni.cpp:9:45: error: 'Hello' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

Comment: your quote for string is also wrong. I've fixed it in my answer. try it

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: For this particular error: 342 200 234 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x9C (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201C ([LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). And 342 200 235 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x9D (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201D ([RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). They can be searched for (and replaced) by the regular expression `\x{201C}|\x{201D}` in any modern text editor (the notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u201C|\u201D`).

Comment: The *taylorpeer.com* link is (effectively) broken. It times out. But it was probably ***copying source code from that web page*** that caused this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `""`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
    Java_com_example_Hellojnicpp_stringFromJNI
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from C++ over JNI!");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me out in my problem which is similar to this. you can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100111/how-to-resolve-android-ndk-build-command-faild

Answer (score 1):

```
extern “C”
```

should be

```
extern "C"
```

i.e., no "curly" quotes. Make sure your text editor does not "beautify" your straight quotes for you.

Comment: changed extern “C” to "C" and now getting the different error

Comment: Hmmm, let's see, you got an errors in a line with curly quotes. I told you not to use curly quotes in that line, and you are still getting a very similar error in *another* line that *also* contains curly quotes. Might I respectfully suggest that you might not yet have enough programming experience to effectively use the Android NDK?